# Connect to mysql database from other device connected with laptop hotspot which is without internet

Tags: android, mysql, server, wifi, sharing

I have to submit project, where I have a mysql database server running on my machine. How can I connect my android device with the server but I am not allowed internet access on the laptop.
I tried creating a hotspot by,

```
netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=YourSSIDName key=YourKey
```

and `netsh wlan start hostednetwork`. My device connects to hotspot but I am unable to connect to the mysql server. I tried with the IP address of the laptop but in vain. Any solutions will be appreciated.

Comment: you have to expose your database to other devices with help of webservices.

Comment: I will have no working internet, will I still be able to connect then?

Comment: as long as server and client are on same network, it will work.